# Script Error em Google Maps - Titanium

Tags: ios, google, maps

Estou tendo uma dificuldade extrema para fazer apenas 3 rotas em meu aplicativo. Estou dias tentando entender a lógica/código exato para finalizar meu projeto e não obtenho sucesso.

Escrevi a linha de código abaixo:

```
var socure = [37.389569, -122.050212];
var destination = [37.422502, -122.0855498];
var mode = "d";

var url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+socure+"&daddr="+destination+"&f=d&sensor=true&doflg=ptm&hl=en&dirflg="+mode+"&output=kml";
```

Está apresentando o seguinte erro:

> Error: [ERROR] :  Script Error { [ERROR] :      backtrace = "#0 () at
>   :0"; [ERROR] :      line = 60; [ERROR] :      message = "Error
>   Domain=com.google.GDataXML Code=-1 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be
>   completed. (com.google.GDataXML error -1.)\"";

Alguém poderia me ajudar nisso?